# Align jQuery List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a mobile website with jQuery, and I was wondering if there was a way to align a list to the bottom of a page, I just want the list to stay at the very bottom of the page, and be fixed in the spot. Thanks

This is the list im trying to get fixed on the bottom of the page:

```
<div  data-role="content">
<div class="content-primary">   
<ul data-role="listview">

<li><a href="link.html"><img src="file.jpg" /><h3>List name</h3></a>
</li>
</div>
```

Comment: You probably want to close your ul tag before that ending div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using position:fixed?

sample: http://jsfiddle.net/zmjhQ/4/

**update**: revised fiddle

Comment: that worked... but now the list is only covering part of the page and its suppose to be stretched across the whole page.

Comment: it'll probably just take some css to clean up the effect. see the revised fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zmjhQ/3/

Comment: its almost perfect... but now its offset by like 10 pixels... like its not aligned to the left completly..

Comment: that was just because of a bit of padding in the <li> tag. just there to keep the list items separate a bit and give a bit of visual relief. no big deal, we can just remove it, and every thing will be flush with the left side: http://jsfiddle.net/zmjhQ/4/

Comment: Sweeeeeeeeeeeeeeet! I added left: 0px; and its working awesome, thanks sooooooo much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use css absolute positioning.

```
#list {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

*edit* based on your code sample, in jquery:

```
$('.content-primary ul').css('position', 'absolute').css('bottom', 0);
```

Comment: That's not working for me, I added the code to my question so you can see exatly what im trying to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery Mobile, you can wrap the element in a div with `data-role="footer"` and it should do what you want.

See this tut in net.tutsplus.com: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-build-an-rss-reader-with-jquery-mobile-2/

Answer (score 0):

As class of div is **CONTENT-PRIMARY** so track this **div** using ""**.** operator of jquery as ::
*emphasized text$('.content-primary')* and then place the part of css in it as explained by Jake Feasel

One thing make sure the class you specify for catching  the div is same as you specify in the property of div class.